# JAVA - Como retirar a ação default do enter em um JOptionPane?

Tags: java, joptionpane

Estou com um JOptionPane com as opções "OK" e "Cancelar". Ao navegar com o Tab entre elas, mesmo que o Cancelar esteja selecionado, ao apertar o Enter ela puxa a opção default, no caso o OK, e confirma a operação. 
Usando o espaço ele funciona de acordo e seleciona, porém preciso que o enter funcione do mesmo jeito que o espaço.

Obs: Tentei utilizar o

```
 UIManager.put("Button.defaultButtonFollowsFocus", Boolean.TRUE);
```

mas não funcionou.

Comment: Relacionada: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10395181/2241463